# Cannot typeset an equation correctly

Tags: math-mode, tabulary

I'm trying to typeset the following equation, but I get complaints about 'missing $ inserted'.

```
\begin{equation} \label{Pearson}
\begin{tabulary} {18cm}{L R @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} L}
&Sim_{a,b}^{PCC}& = 
& $\displaystyle \frac{
  \sum_{P\in P}( r_{a,p} - \overline {r}a)( r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)} {%
  {\sqrt{\sum_{P\in P}( r_{a,p} - \overline{r}a)^2}}
  {\sqrt{\sum_{P\in P}( r_{b,p} - \overline{r}b)^2}}}$
\end{tabulary}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) full minimal example please. How are `L`, 'R` etc defined? NMormally these are lower case. (3) You have math in call 2, does `R` take case of this? Now you know why we always ask for a full minimal example that others can copy and test withoput adding anything or having to guess.

Comment: `tabulary` is designed for tables with large amounts of _text_ to adjust line breaking, you almost certainly should not be using it here at all, this seems to be a math alignment so `align` or `aligned` would be more suitable. the error is because you have math markup `_` and `^` in the `R` column which is a text column.

Comment: @daleif tabulary columns are LCR (but using `tabulary with math is somewhat strange!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see no reason for employing a 4-column `tabulary` environment; an `equation` environment is all you need.

I would, though, replace all instances of `\overline` with `\bar`. And it should be `\sum_{p\in P}` rather than `\sum_{P\in P}`, and `\bar{r}_a` and `\bar{r}_b` rather than `\bar{r}a` and `\bar{r}b`, right?

If you have several equations which need to be aligned on their respective `=` symbols, do look into employing the `align` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{Pearson}
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} = \frac{%
\sum_{p\in P}( r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)(r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b)} {%
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)^2}
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{b,p}-\bar{r}_b)^2}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```