# Bad math environment delimiters and misplaced alignment tab

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I have this multiline equation and I have this error. I need to make it in a paper with two column

```
\begin{equation} \label{Mult-PCC}
\[ & Sim_{a_,_b}^{PCC} &= &
\left \{
\begin{tabulary}
{18cm}{L R @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} L}

  Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_1,   if \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}\geq   t1 \;   and \;   Sim_{i_j_,_i_q}^{PCC} \geq y\\
   \\
    Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_2, \;  if \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t1 \; and  \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t2 \; and    \; Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_3, \;  if \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t2 \; and  \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t3 \; and    \; Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_4, \;  if \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t3 \; and  \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t4 \; and    \; Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    0, \;\;\;\;\;otherwise

\end{tabulary}
\right \}
\]
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You cannot put `\[...\]` inside an `equation` environment, nor use the alignment keys `&`, which you could use inside `align` for instance.

Comment: This is exactly the same issue as your previous question and you have not addressed any of the comments there, the tabulary LCR columns are for text but you have math markup (and tabulary is not appropriate here at all)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451375/cannot-typeset-an-equation-correctly

Comment: Why do you keep trying to use a `tabulary` environment in a setting for which it is utterly unsuited? `tabulary` environments are not meant to be used to typeset equations. The sooner you get rid of this bad habit, the better.

Comment: The `tabulary` package has existed for more than 20 years, during which I found a few cases where I found it to solve a problem I had; never for math typesetting and you can trust me I typeset *a lot* of math.

Comment: Is it possible to have this equation in one column since I have a two column format for a paper

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt at providing a workable solution. As in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451414/5001) provided by @marmot, the main formatting tool is the `cases` environment. I've also gotten rid of the `tabulary` overhead as well as of a lot of unnecessary (and erroneous) `_` and `|` symbols, deleted all `\;` spacers, and placed all instances of `if`, `and` and `otherwise` in `\text` wrappers; that way, these words will be typeset in the text font (almost certainly an upright font) rather than in math-italic font. Moreover, in rows 2 thru 4, I've combined the two separate inequalities into a single two-part inequalities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'cases' environment

\newcommand\PCC{\mathrm{PCC}}
\newcommand\Sim{\mathrm{Sim}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation} \label{Mult-PCC} 
\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} =
\begin{cases}
\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} + x_1 
 &\text{if }\phantom{t2\leq{}}\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}\geq t_1
  \text{ and }\Sim_{ij,iq}^{\PCC} \geq y\\[1ex]
\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} + x_2 
 &\text{if }t_2\leq\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_1
  \text{ and }\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} \geq y \\[1ex]
\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} + x_3 
 &\text{if }t_3\leq\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_2
  \text{ and }\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} \geq y \\[1ex]
\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} + x_4 
 &\text{if }t_4\leq\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_3
  \text{ and }\Sim_{a,b}^{\PCC} \geq y \\[1ex]
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and sloppy attempt to repair your code. At least it is compilable and the output is readable. I guess you should try to understand what went wrong in your previous attempt first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sim}{Sim}
\begin{document}

\begin{align} \label{Mult-PCC}
 \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} &= 
\begin{cases}
  \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_1, &  \text{if }\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}\geq   t_1 \;  \text{ and }\;   \Sim_{ij,iq}^{PCC} \geq y\\
   \\
    \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_2, & \text{if }\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_1 \text{ and } \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t_2 \text{ and }   \; \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_3,& \text{if }\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_2 \text{ and } \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t_3 \text{ and }   \; \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} + x_4, & \text{if }\frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T} < t_3 \text{ and } \frac{|I_a\cap I_b|}{T}| \geq t_4 \text{ and }   \; \Sim_{a,b}^{PCC} \geq y \\
    \\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I would also replace all instances of `PCC` with `\textrm{PCC}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I know. There are many options, and I saw you were using `\textit` in your nice answer that I just upvoted. As long as we do not know the context, we will have to speculate what `Sim` really is. My guess was that it is a function, but of course that could be completely wrong, yet I hesitate to change it until I really know what it really is.

Comment: My hunch is that "PCC" stands for "Pearson correlation coefficient". But it's just a hunch... I don't any idea what "Sim" might stand for...

Comment: @Mico I dunno, maybe "Super intelligent Mico" or "Super intelligent marmot"? ;-)